# Rails: Dependent Fields inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement dependent fields in my application. For that I'm using the [dependent-fields-rails](https://github.com/vollnhals/dependent-fields-rails) gem. I've set up everything with [this tutorial](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/dependent-form-fields). The good thing: It works. Kind of. In my **brand model** I have brands listet such as Adidas, Nike, ...

Now my two challenges:

1. I don't know what I have to fill in to the `data-option-value=" "` field because I want to show the select form for the category if a Brand is selected at all and not a specific one. If I put a value in the field (hardcoded) like `data-option-value="Adidas"` the category_select form only appears if I've chosen "Adidas" from the Brand dropdown.
2. I want to show only the matching categories for the Brand that was selected in step 1. My **group model** contains also the brand record so I can match a category to the brand.

To make it a bit more clear:

- Brand model contains companies like Adidas, Nike, ...
- Group model contains categories like Footwear, Shirts, ...

Here's what I got:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :brand %>
  <%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company).uniq, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
</div>
<div class="form-group js-dependent-fields" data-select-id='warehouse_brand' data-option-value="Adidas">
  <%= f.label :category %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:category, Group.all, :brand, :name1, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
</div>
```

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this actually works:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :brand %>
  <%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company).uniq, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
</div>
<% Brand.all.each do |b| %>
  <div class="form-group js-dependent-fields" data-option-value="<%= b.company %>" data-select-id="warehouse_brand">
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category, Group.where(brand: b.company), :brand, :name1, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a brand has many groups. If you don't want to use hard coded values then put the js-dependent-fields in a loop as shown in the code below.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :brand %>
  <%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company).uniq, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
</div>
<% Brand.all.each do |b| %>
  <div class="form-group js-dependent-fields" data-option-value= "#{b.company}" data-select-id="warehouse_brand">
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category, Group.where(brand_id: "#{b.id}"), :brand, :name1, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To show only the matching categories you can write a query that selects the related to the brand as shown in the code

```
Group.where(brand_id: "#{b.id}")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The HTML Output is "data-option-value="#{b.company}""


<div class="form-group js-dependent-fields" data-option-value="#{b.company}" data-select-id="warehouse_brand" style="display: none;">
        <label for="warehouse_category">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="warehouse[category]" id="warehouse_category"><option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
      </div>